# Java Wireless Toolkit: Exporting data from a running midlet

Tags: java, java-me, midlet

I have an midlet running on JWT, and i want to export some data evaluated by the app. to some other application, or just able to get it to command line so i can send it as a param to some ather application.

Is it possible to send some data (values of a return function or a variable) to out of JWT, or is there any console or logging info for reaiding related data from.

Since midlet is based on some graphics and graphical form fields, i can not run it from command line.

Comment: not quite getting it. how do you expect to find the variables you want to export if you can't read the decompiled bytecode?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write the data to a file using the FileConnection API? There's a [tutorial available](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/).

Comment: Problem is, I do not have the java code, but a pre-built jar file. Decompile-Recompile is useless, since it is a complicated code. Somehow i need to export that values, by means of JWT or some other application

Comment: Wow.... that's a tricky situation. The only thing I can think of is running the emulator in debug mode and attaching a remote debugger to it. You are still going to have to find the correct places to put breakpoints in, though so without source code it's going to be quite hard core.